# Azure AD B2C - Token validation does not work

Tags: jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I would like to use Azure AD B2C but have several difficulties using it.
One problem I have is to validate the signature of the token.
First I wanted to validate the token "manually" using jwt.io.

According to the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-the-signature), validating the signature should work like this:

> Your app can use the  kid  claim in the JWT header to select the public key in the JSON document that is used to sign a particular token. It can then perform signature validation by using the correct public key and the indicated algorithm.

My understandig: Grab the kid value out of the header, lookup the key in the metadata under the location of jwks_uri, (assumption) use the value of "n" to verify the signature.

[image]

But Jwt.io, jsonwebtoken.io, and jose-jwt all say, that the **signature is invalid.**

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Jwt.io seems to only support HS265 with a string secret and RS256 with a string secret or a certificate**.

**Azure AD B2C uses the more native form of RS256** which as per [RFC 3447, section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-3.1) defines that the public key consists of two components: `n` and `e`. The JWK contains both `n` and `e` which can be used to generate public key and validate the token signature.

In order to use Jwt.io, you'll need to convert Azure AD B2C's n + e format for the key to a cert format. See this example for a reference on how to do this: [Go Language Convert Modulus exponent to X.509 certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127019/go-language-convert-modulus-exponent-to-x-509-certificate)

Comment: That was it! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I was finally able to turn the modulus and exponent to PEM format [using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406888/c-sharp-rsa-public-key-output-not-correct/28407693#28407693) and was able to verify the signatrue using jwt.io and c#.

Comment: would love to use jwt.io for this, [posted a thread to their forum](https://community.auth0.com/questions/7687/cant-verify-signature-of-jwt-from-azure-b2c)

Comment: jwt.ms will perform validation on AAD and AAD B2C tokens as well as decode

Answer (score 6):

There is now a way to validate tokens using two npm packages.

## Resources

The information was made available at: [Microsoft - Example-verifying-validation-tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-with-resource-data?view=graph-rest-1.0#example-verifying-validation-tokens)

### Package Versions Used

- [jwks-rsa: "1.8.1"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwks-rsa/v/1.8.1)
- [jsonwebtoken: "8.5.1"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken/v/8.5.1)

### How To

The example below was modified from example in [Microsoft - Example-verifying-validation-tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks-with-resource-data?view=graph-rest-1.0#example-verifying-validation-tokens)

#### Retrieving "Issuer" and "User Flow" Name Values From Azure

[image: Screenshot of Azure portal for]

#### Retrieving Application Id

[image]

#### Code Example

```js
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import jkwsClient from 'jwks-rsa';

// Variables that need to be defined based on your Azure B2C Configuration.
const jwksUri = 'https://MY-B2C-TENANT.b2clogin.com/MY-B2C-TENANT.onmicrosoft.com/MY-USER-FLOW-NAME/discovery/v2.0/keys';

const client = jkwsClient({
  jwksUri
});

export function getKey(header, callback) {
  client.getSigningKey(header.kid, (err, key) => {
    var signingKey = key.getPublicKey();
    callback(null, signingKey);
  });
}

export function isTokenValid(token, applicationId, issuerUri) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const options = {
      audience: [applicationId],
      issuer: [issuerUri]
    };
    jwt.verify(token, getKey, options, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.error('Jwt Validation Failed', err);
        resolve(false);
      } else {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console        
        console.debug(decoded)
        resolve(true);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

#### Usage

```js
const applicationId = 'APPLICATION ID OF B2C TENANT'
const issuerUri = 'In the User Flow Properties'

const valid = isTokenValid('some token value without "Bearer", applicationId, issuerUri);
```

### Notes

- The `jwksUri` contains the user "User Policy". If you have multiple "User Policies", you will need to figure out how to instantiate the `jkwsClient` with correct `jwksUri` based on the each "User Policy" flow.
- While you can leverage [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) or [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms), a token can be decoded in the debugger console. This will give you some key information such as the "iss" (Issuer) and the "kid":

```js
'e3R5cDogIkpXVCIsIGFsZzogIlJTMjU2Iiwga2lkOiAiWU9VX1NORUFLWV9SQUJCSVQifQ==.e2V4cDogMTU5NjYwMTc4NiwgbmJmOiAxNTk2NTk4MTg2LCB2ZXI6ICIxLjAiLCBpc3M6ICJodHRwczovL3doaXRlLXJhYmJpdC5iMmNsb2dpbi5jb20vZjIzNDZhMzBhLTk1ODEtNGU0ZC04MWQwLWQyZjk4NTQ3MWJhOS92Mi4wLyIsIHN1YjogImYzMmNjNmJhLWE5MTctNGE1Ni1hYjhmLWIyNGZmMTg1ODUyOCIsICIuLi4iOiAibW9yZSB2YWx1ZXMuLi4ifQ==.UNODECODEME'.split('.').map((value, index) => { 
   // The signature can't be decoded
   if(index > 1) { return value; }
     return atob(value);
   });
```

Comment: You deserve a medal this is the best documentation I have found about this topic.

Comment: Something that might help other... here is an example of a valid issuer URI `issuer = 'https://ugrose.b2clogin.com/9c2984ff-d596-4e5c-8e74-672be7b592e3/v2.0/' # iss`

Comment: This article is a good complement to this answer https://robertoprevato.github.io/Validating-JWT-Bearer-tokens-from-Azure-AD-in-Python/

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://play.golang.org/p/7wWMBOp10R to get a public key from modulus(n) and exponent(e). Then copy the entire output in jwt.io and you'll see the signature is valid.