# Where's the Key for My Azure AD B2C Token?

Tags: jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I'm [following this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens?#validate-the-signature) and using the [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) chrome addin but I can't find my key so that I can manually verify the signature.

**JWT Header**

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "c9HOlAkfaBs4YSKZ7RoMnZlKrVzdkXHB2QoLv1fETQ8"
}
```

The [OpenID Connect metadata document](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration) leads me to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys but that response not have this kid.

I've also referenced this [blog post](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2017/01/24/Verifying-Azure-Active-Directory-JWT-Tokens.aspx).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The URL to retrieve your Azure AD B2C tenant's keys has the following format:**

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/<tenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_<policyName>/discovery/v2.0/keys
```

For example:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_edit_profile/discovery/v2.0/keys

Note that both the keys and URLs are different from those for regular Azure AD and Azure AD's v2.0 endpoint (the latter being the URL you referenced in your question).

At this time, the keys for all [built-in policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies) (even across tenants) use the same keys, however in the case of [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom) you'll see different keys per tenant and even in some cases, per policy.

**Important note**: You won't be able to use jwt.io out of the box to validate Azure AD B2C tokens given that the keys in Azure AD B2C are in a different format. 
See [Azure AD B2C - Token validation does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330242/azure-ad-b2c-token-validation-does-not-work)

Comment: That worked but I'm at a loss.  Why couldn't I follow the guide?  Is is out of date maybe?

Comment: You were looking at the docs for (regluar) Azure AD's v2 endpoint which is different from Azure AD B2C. They have different metadata URLs and keys.

Comment: gotcha, thanks!  Here: [Azure AD B2C: Token reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-tokens)

Answer (score 11):

This answer is quite old and the URL as at October 2021 is now:

`https://<tenantName>.b2clogin.com/<tenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_<policyName>/discovery/v2.0/keys`

Comment: Mentioned in the other post, but this has been updated and is just as relavant [Overview of tokens - Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview)