# Azure B2C RSA Public Key to PEM Certificate

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

A software system from a collaborating company needs to connect to one of our systems and authenticate against our Azure-B2C Directory. They would like to verify the signature in our JWT Token returned.

I have created a RSA Public Key using the approach described in this topic:
[Azure AD B2C - Token validation does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330242/azure-ad-b2c-token-validation-does-not-work)

This has resulted in the following RSA Public Key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA959e/O3gE574tAdjfjE6
+6OgTBsTGGbDTHBn/w137OTKoH3MnbOX16rrfumVZOr2GisCtIwxJM8ziiqvG1Fj
*more key*
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I've used this RSA Public Key to verify the signature of my token in jwt.io, and it works.

The collaborating company however needs a PEM certificate like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA959e/O3gE574tAdjfjE6
+6OgTBsTGGbDTHBn/w137OTKoH3MnbOX16rrfumVZOr2GisCtIwxJM8ziiqvG1Fj
*more key*
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Modifying the PEM Header of my RSA Public Key does not work.
So now my question is: Is it possible to convert my RSA Public Key to the appropriate Certificate format? If yes, how?

Comment: Hi @AgitioM Can you use an online converter such as [this](https://superdry.apphb.com/tools/online-rsa-key-converter)?

Comment: @Chris Padgett thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't work, the certificate option is not available in that converter.