# Invalid signature Azure access token jwt.io

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, jwt

I generated access tokens using Azure AD+ Spring Boot using Outh2 Authorization code grant flow.
But when I try to validate the token generated (using Spring Boot resource server apis) I get an "Invalid Signature" Error.

Question is I get "Invalid Signature" error when I copy/paste the token in jwt.io as well.

[Jwt.io image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCvZx.png)

Does that mean that my access token does not actually have a valid signature ??

When I switched the Algorithm from RS256 to HS256 in jwt.io it says that the signature was verified.  Which I found strange.

Is there any way I can know what algorithm is used by Azure AD to generate Access tokens  after successful user login??

Comment: What was the resource/scope you used when acquiring the token?

Comment: I am currently strugling with the same issue, on ios. Tried changing to HS256 and it certainly does change to "Signature Verified". I found these two links which may be of help. https://stackoverflow.com/q/50816301/319826 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/44330242/319826. HTH.

Comment: Changing the algorithm to "HS256" on jwt.io causes a recalculation of the signature and the recalculated signature is of course valid, but that does not mean that you verified the original token. When you paste a token, the verification is based on the alg value in the header. It doesn't make sense to change it manually.

Comment: HI Juunas,   scope used is : openid,profile.

Comment: The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41132320/319826 have a link to a Go-program at https://go.dev/play/p/Ch6Nr9F6Ik which you can copy and compile on your machine. It produces a RSA PUBLIC KEY in PEM-format but I did not get a valid signature with this.

Comment: Hi Kometen , from what I have looked at in StackOverflow it looks like you cannot validate the access tokens with scope Open Id  atleast in my case . Below is the link for reference,      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65149128/azure-access-token-invalid-signature-in-jwt-io?rq=1

Comment: Thank you, this is very interesting. It seems I need to create a client secret in the mobile app's "Certificates & secrets".

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I generated **Authorization code** by using the below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 

client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=RedirectURI 
&response_mode=query  
&scope=openid profile
&state=12345
```

[image]

I generated the **access token using Authorization code grant flow** using Postman by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:openid profile
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:RedirectURI 
code:code
```

[image]

***When I decoded the above access token, I got the same error like below:***

[image]

> **Note** that:  Graph API token doesn't require validation (`aud` is Graph). Graph access token will not pass Signature verification in the code because access token is not for the application.

**To resolve the issue**, you can try replacing the **scope** as `api://ClientIDofApp/.default` while generating the token like below:

[image]

The **access token decoded successfully** without any error like below:

[image]

**Reference:**

[openid - Signed JWT rejected: Invalid signature azure-spring-boot (github.com)](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-spring-boot/issues/476#issuecomment-618810475)

Comment: value of scope when we get the access_token should be {clientId}/.default and not api://{clientId}/.default